# Extracting coordinate of an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, coordinates

I am trying to write a method to extract the array coordinate that matches a number I have predefined:

So here is my code at the moment:

```
public static int matsrch(double[][]B, double S) {
    int []A = {0, 0};
    for (int i=1; i<3; i++) {
        for (int j=1; j<3; j++) {
            if (B[i][j] == S) {
                 A = {i, j};
                 return A;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do you output an *array* from a method?

Comment: `for` loop: array index starts from `0` not `1`

Comment: Well, if you want to return an array from you're method you'd start by declaring the method to return an array, not an int.

Comment: why do I start from 0 and not 1??

Answer (score 0):

> How do you output an array from a method?

You're on the right track by using `return`.

Declare the method as returning an array:

```
public static int[] matsrch( ... ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your method as int[]:

```
public static int[] matsrch( ... )
```

and add `i` and `j` values to `A` before returning:

```
A[0] = i;
A[1] = j;
```